# Randomly named modules

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, module

When I debug certain applications (using Visual Studio 2005) I notice strange, randomly named modules are loaded. The names change each time. But they are like di-leyes, jnilel-e, lkmjelxl, llufvuwr. The module path is always identical to the module name. And the module timestamp seems to be the time when the module was loaded.

So it seems that randomly named modules are being created and loaded into the app, which sounds pretty scary.

Has any one seen anything like this? Or can anyone give me some tips on how to figure out what these are?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the files to see what they do. Mostly they are XML serializers for the types you serialized in your code but forgot to generate corresponding XML serializer assemblies. You probably want to use Visual Studio or SGen to generate XML serializer assemblies because .Net generates one assembly for each type and if you have a lot of types, your memory would be wasted and fragmented by these assemblies and their overheads.